# How to make UI Button to rotate an gameobject?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, gameobject

I'm trying to make a button to make a gameobject rotate and stay rotating in its own axis (Y) but I cannot make it work...

As far as I know it's very simple:

1. Create an empty gameobject (or whatever you want)
2. Make a script and attach it to the gameobject
3. Create `public` methods
4. Link the gameobject with the script attached to the button `onClick` event
5. Click the button and test the script

My problem is that I don't know how I'm wrong here are the scripts of my project

This first script is my attempt using keys, and it works like charm

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TurntableRotation : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject turntable;
    public float turnSpeed;
    public bool canRotate = false;

    void Start () 
    {
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        StartTurntableRotation();

        StopTurntableRotation();
    }

    public void StartTurntableRotation()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.I))
            {
                canRotate = true;
            }

            if (canRotate)
            {
                turntable.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
    }

    public void StopTurntableRotation()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
        {
            canRotate = false;
        }

        if (!canRotate)
        {
            turntable.transform.Rotate(0,0,0);
        }
    }
}
```

This second script is my work in progress

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TurntableUIBtns : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public GameObject turntable;
    public float turnSpeed;

        //This is my public method used by the button
    public void StartTurntableBtn()
    {

                //This is my attempt to write the code for the object to rotate
        turntable.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

As far as my knowledge goes, it is supposed to work, but I have to click every time to rotate my object, my goal is to click the button and make the object rotate and stay rotating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool canRotate = false;
void Update()
{
    if(canRotate)
        turntable.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
//Your button Method
public void StartRotation()
{
    canRotate = !canRotate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s because you need to use the Rotate function in Update, just like you do in your first script. You can simply use a bool again.